# php7 mongodb driver ObjectId not found

Tags: php, mongodb

I follow the instructions on [mongodb/mongo-php-library](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-php-library) official repository

```
$ pecl install mongodb
$ echo "extension=mongodb.so" >> `php --ini | grep "Loaded Configuration" | sed -e "s|.*:\s*||"`
```

but when i try to execute a test with phpunit over this constructor:

```
    use MongoDB\BSON\ObjectID;

    (...)

    /**
     * X constructor.
     *
     * @param ObjectID|null $id
     */
    public function __construct(ObjectID $id = null)
    {
        if (!$id) {
            $id = new ObjectID();
        }

        $this->id = $id;
    }

    (...)
```

i got this error

```
1) tests\X\X\XTest::testBeConstructed
Error: Class 'MongoDB\BSON\ObjectID' not found
```

## EDIT

if i create a test file with this single line of code:

```
<?php

echo new \MongoDB\BSON\ObjectID();
```

and i execute it with

```
php test.php
```

it shows:

```
581ddc9c6fb3720352664f11
```

## SECOND EDIT

As adviced in the comments i put some debug lines at first line on my phpunit tests:

```
var_dump(extension_loaded('mongodb'));
echo phpversion().PHP_EOL;
print_r(get_loaded_extensions());
```

here is the output

```
bool(true)
7.0.8-0ubuntu0.16.04.3
Array
(
    [0] => Core
    [1] => date
    [2] => libxml
    [3] => openssl
    [4] => pcre
    [5] => zlib
    [6] => filter
    [7] => hash
    [8] => pcntl
    [9] => Reflection
    [10] => SPL
    [11] => session
    [12] => standard
    [13] => phpdbg
    [14] => mysqlnd
    [15] => PDO
    [16] => xml
    [17] => bcmath
    [18] => calendar
    [19] => ctype
    [20] => curl
    [21] => dom
    [22] => mbstring
    [23] => fileinfo
    [24] => ftp
    [25] => gd
    [26] => gettext
    [27] => iconv
    [28] => intl
    [29] => json
    [30] => exif
    [31] => mcrypt
    [32] => mysqli
    [33] => pdo_mysql
    [34] => Phar
    [35] => posix
    [36] => readline
    [37] => shmop
    [38] => SimpleXML
    [39] => sockets
    [40] => sysvmsg
    [41] => sysvsem
    [42] => sysvshm
    [43] => tokenizer
    [44] => wddx
    [45] => xmlreader
    [46] => xmlwriter
    [47] => xsl
    [48] => Zend OPcache
)
PHPUnit 5.6.2 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.
```

im running phpunit with the following command

```
phpdbg -qrr /root/.composer/vendor/bin/phpunit
```

Why is phpunit not recognizing the mongodb ext?

What im missing?

Thanks

NOTE: if you wonder why im root is because this is inside a docker container

Comment: What was the output of the commands? I guess, you have executed them as a normal user, and the extension is not installed due to insufficient privileges. Check if the extension is loaded: `php -m | grep -i mongo`.

Comment: @RuslanOsmanov the library compiled just fine and installed ok. the output to the command, you mention; execution was: mongodb

Comment: Have you tested the script in command line? Maybe other SAPIs (Apache, FPM, etc.) load `php.ini` from different paths.

Comment: Sorry @RuslanOsmanov dont get your last comment, what specifically should i do?

Comment: Ah, sorry. I thought of another problem. Of course you have launched phpunit from CLI.

Comment: This is really wear, if i create a test file with this single line echo new \MongoDB\BSON\ObjectID(); it shows 581ddc9c6fb3720352664f11 as expected. Why phpunit its not finding the mongodb ext? @RuslanOsmanov

Comment: put `var_dump(extension_loaded('mongodb'));` at the beginning of the unit test. If it prints `false`, then phpunit is likely using different version of php

Comment: @RuslanOsmanov as advice i put the debug lines, you can see on main question second edit. Really confusing why is phpunit not loading those extensions

Answer (score 0):

This was a really novice issue, i install phpdbg after i compile and install the mongodb extension, so for phpdbg installation the mongodb extension was not loaded. I enable it for it and it works.